# How to send email to people via Google Plus API?

Tags: gmail, google-plus, google-hangouts

According to **Google Plus**, you can e-mail Google Plus users within your circle: [refer this](http://www.theverge.com/2014/1/9/5292310/gmail-now-lets-you-send-emails-to-other-google-users)

- How can you use the Google Plus API (or Gmail API) to send an e-mail to a user within your circle, given you have their user ID?
- If you cannot do this, how can you send them a message via hangouts?

Comment: As per the article,you can basically search any Google user by name,without actually knowing their name via Google Plus,mail or other google apps.Could you please be more clear as to from which external application do you wish to send out mail(for which Google API integration needs to be done accordingly)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should follow the official Gmail API reference guide [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet).

From the docs:

> There are two ways to send email using the Gmail API:
>
> - You can send it directly using the [messages.send](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send) method.
> - You can send it from a draft, using the [drafts.send](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/send) method.
>
> Emails are sent as
>   base64url encoded strings within the `raw` property of a [message
>   resource](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages). The high-level workflow to send an email is to:
>
> Create the email content in some convenient way and encode it as a
>   base64url string. Create a new message resource and set its raw
>   property to the base64url string you just created. Call `messages.send`,
>   or, if sending a draft, `drafts.send` to send the message.

The arguments you'll need to provide in order to send an email through the API are the following:

```
Args:
    - service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
    - user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
               can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
    - message: Message to be sent.
```